# How to add variables to Twig

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I want to add some values to a Twig object, to be used when I render()/display() the template.  Something like an "assign" function.  All I can find in the documentation is to pass an array to render()/display().

For example, I want the flow to look like:

```
$Twig = MakeNewTwigEtc();
...
...
$Twig->assign('error','Bad username/password');
...
...
$Twig->display('login-form.html');
...
Twig template file can now output error with {{ error }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example with error message is not very siutable for this situation, usually error messages are sent by flashbags, but if you want to declare some global twig variables there are some ways you can do:

1. in `parameters.yml` file set the variable - for ex, `sitename: Site Name`, in `config.yml` file under `twig` section -> `globals` section set it,

for ex:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    globals:
        sitename: "%sitename%"
```

after that you can use it in your template files like `sitename`

2. if your variable is more complicated , you can extend Twig, add global variable with `addGlobal()` method, you can find [more information here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals)

Comment: addGlobal() is exactly what I wanted - thanks.  Regarding the error message - what I'm doing is reading from the flashed messages, then putting them in my template.  However, I'm doing that in my base controller - before the action gets executed, so I can't just include it in the array passed to display().